# os.startfile saying file doesn't exist but it does?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I am trying to select a random music file from a folder in Python using the windows commands: `random.choice()` `os.listdir()` `os.startfile()`

Here is the code:

`import os, random
song = random.choice(os.listdir("C:\Users\MASONF\Music\Downloaded"))
os.startfile(song)`

It returns the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MASONF\Desktop\successfuly chosen random file non existent.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.startfile(song)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Panda Eyes - Drippy Dub.mp3'`

The file exists but it can't find it? I am new to Python and don't know many commands for anything so I have probably missed something obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need add the base path to the song name:

```
import os, random
path = r"C:\Users\MASONF\Music\Downloaded"
song = random.choice(os.listdir(path))
os.startfile(path+'\\'+song)
```